# Parameter is null in jsp when trying to get JSON object

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json, jsp

I'm trying to pass a JSON object from jquery to a jsp. The jquery code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("form").on("submit", function(event){
            event.preventDefault();

            var formData = JSON.stringify(jQuery("form").serializeArray());
            $.post("<%=request.getRequestURL().toString()%>getInfo.jsp", formData);
    });

});
```

On the JSP side, my code to get the object is:

```
out.println(request.getParameter("formData"));
```

The console just outputs "null".

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is no incoming form variable named "formData".  Change this line as follows:

```
$.post("<%=request.getRequestURL().toString()%>getInfo.jsp", { formData: formData} );
```

Answer (score 0):

`formData` is not a parameter. The parameter would be the names of your inputs.

ex

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="test"></input>
</form>
```

Would be retrieved using `request.getParameter("test");`